# Kinesics Text Editor and Git

Tags: git

I want to use the Kinesics Text Editor (http://turtlewar.org/projects/editor/) as my text editor when I use Git.

I've tried

```
git config --global core.editor "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kinesics Text Editor\x64\k.exe"
```

but when I run

`git config --edit`

it throws an error

[image]

Is there a way to get this editor to be my default text editor in Git?

I am also unable to just run k (or k.exe) from the **git** prompt. From the normal command prompt k.exe runs normally.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

Inside your home directory create a file called 'k.sh'. Inside type the following and save:

```
winpty "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kinesics Text Editor\x64\k.exe"
```

Next run the command:

```
git config --global core.editor '~/k.sh'
```

This appears to do the trick!